# Oracle multiple databases on same server

Tags: oracle

I want to be able to import multiple database dumps locally and be able to switch between them.

What I would like to achieve:

1. Import dumps (objects+data) from multiple databases to local database
2. Switch between imported databases (`db1` and `db2`) locally

`db1` and `db2` have users/schemas/objects/etc with same name and this shouldn't cause a conflict.

---

Expected result would be following:

- connect with one USERNAME/PASSWORD and query tables from schema named MYSCHEMA and then `db1` data would be used.
- "switch" active database (by passing some additional parameter on connecting) or executing some command.
- now same USERNAME/PASSWORD combination and querying tables from MYSCHEMA should return data from `db2`

Comment: Read about [pluggable databases](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/cdbovrvw.htm#CNCPT89245)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Multitenant option, create a container database, create 2 pluggable databases called `db1` and `db2`, then import the first dump file to `db1`, the other dump file to `db2`.

You can switch between pluggable databases with as:

```
alter session set container=db1;
alter session set container=db2
```

But this requires at least version 12c, and it is an extra cost option.

For lower versions, or without the Multitenant option:

Simply create 2 traditional databases on the server: `db1` and `db2`. Import one dump to `db1`, the other to `db2`. You can specify in your connection string the service (or SID) for the database you want to connect to. For example:

```
sqlplus user/password@hostname/db1
sqlplus user/password@hostname/db2
```